# Anychart: how to combine Jump line and multiseries column chart?

Tags: anychart

I'm trying to combine a jump line with a multiseries column chart. Is it possible to create a jump line specifically for each column of the multiseries column chart? For now the only thing that i could obtain is a jump line for each group of the dataset, here's an example:

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

   var data = [
      ["January", 12000, 10000, 8100],
      ["February", 15000, 12000, 8200],
      ["March", 16000, 18000, 8300],
    ];

    var dataSet = anychart.data.set(data);
    var mapping1 = dataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 1});
    var mapping2 = dataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 2});
    var jump1 = dataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 3});

    // create a chart
    var chart = anychart.column();

    // create the series and set the data
    var series1 = chart.column(mapping1);
    var series2 = chart.column(mapping2);

    var series3 = chart.jumpLine(jump1);
    series3.stroke("3 #FFFF00");

    chart.container("container");
    chart.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your idea correctly, then you can create an additional xScale and xAxis. Then bind the jump series to that additional scale. Here is [the live sample based on your code](https://playground.anychart.com/W26SPUTR).

Comment: Thanks for your support. Combining the example you had provided me and the the method pointWidth() I was able to reach out my goal.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs this, thanks to [@AnyChart Support](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3951036/anychart-support) 's answer here's the code for combining this two chart.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

  var data = [
    ["January", 12000, 10000],
    ["February", 15000, 12000],
    ["March", 16000, 18000],
  ];
  var jumpData = [
    ['January_1', 1000],
    ['January_2', 3000],
    ['February_1', 5000],
    ['February_2', 6000],
    ['March_1', 5000],
    ['March_2', 7500],
  ];

  var dataSet = anychart.data.set(data);
  var jumpDataSet = anychart.data.set(jumpData);
  var mapping1 = dataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 1});
  var mapping2 = dataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 2});
  var jump1 = jumpDataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 1});

  // create a chart
  var chart = anychart.column();
  chart.barGroupsPadding(1);
    // Set the padding between bars or columns.
  chart.barsPadding(1);
  


  // create the series and set the data
  var series1 = chart.column(mapping1);
  var series2 = chart.column(mapping2);

  var additionalXscale = anychart.scales.ordinal();
  chart.xAxis(1).scale(additionalXscale).enabled(false);

  var series3 = chart.jumpLine(jump1);
  series3.pointWidth('60%');
  series3.xScale(additionalXscale);
  series3.stroke("5 #00FF00");
series3.name = "AAA"
  chart.container("container");
  chart.draw();
});
```